# MVC SPA application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I am designing an ASP.NET MVC based SPA. The other parts are working fine, however the following is giving a 504 error. I have alerts added to the JavaScript to see how far it goes. Sometimes the I get 504 even before the function in controller is called and sometime 504 is received after controller returns the values.

Model:

```cs
public class CountryModel
{
    public List<Stat> Stats { get; set;  }
}

public class Stat
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Int64 Count { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
public JsonResult GetStats(string code )
{
    //Code will be used for other calculations. 
    List<Stat> tStat = new List<Stat>();

    Stat stat = new Stat();
    stat.Key = "AAA";
    stat.Value = "1000";
    stat.Count = 111;
    tStat.Add(stat);

    stat = new Stat();
    stat.Key = "BBB";
    stat.Value = "2000";
    tStat.Add(stat);

    stat = new Stat();
    stat.Key = "CCC";
    stat.Value = "3000";
    tStat.Add(stat);

    var stats = tStat;
    return Json(stats);
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplicationrazor.Models.CountryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>
    My SPA. 
</h4>
@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
    <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="javascript:Search('myCode');" />

    <br />
    <br />
}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function Search(_code) {
    alert("A1");
    var url = "/Home/GetStats/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { code: _code },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (stats) {
            alert("Success-1");
            ......
            alert("Success-3");
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse.responseXML);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Unless the app is very small I would take a step back and redesign using a proper spa framework like angular or react as the presentation layer and then use asp.net web api as the backend interface. That would be a cleaner approach to an SPA. I have tried it with MVC when v5 first came out with javascript and it turned into spaghetti code real fast.

Comment: May be surround your JavaScript function in `document.ready`